# Stop iPhone loading compressed images

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

When I view a JPEG image on my iPhone, it apparently load a compressed version of the image (pressumably to save network bandwidth).  It has heavy artefacting and makes much of the text on the jpeg unreadable.

I know the answer to this question is probably no, but is there any way to force it to load the original image served by the webserver?  Any creative solutions?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. can you post a link to the image with this behavior?

Comment: Here' an image: http://www.helloblog.co.uk/images/101109/neo_magazine_large.jpg

I'm currently on Edge/3G and it seem to be less compressed than when only on basic network, however even on Edge you can still see artefacting which doesn't exist on the image viewed via desktop.

Comment: This isn't programming related.

Comment: Actually it is, I was not aware it was specific to the O2 cellular network, and was looking for a creative programatic solution, or HTML code on how to serve high quality images to bypass the compression, hence why I tagged the question with HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who is your data provider? Which country?

Google yields [one way](http://www.edandersen.com/2008/07/13/iphone-o2-fix-the-image-compression/) to do it for O2 in the UK.

Comment: I'm on O2 in the UK, I have no means of testing on other networks and am hoping for a solution to fit all.

Comment: AFAIK it is an O2 specific problem.